# Multiple values for argument 'index'

Tags: python, optimization, data-driven

I got the error

```
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'index'
```

when I tried to formulate an optimisation problem using data

```
training_data = data

problem = DataProblem(
    data=training_data,
    variable_names=["h", "b", "l", "t"],
    objective_names=["f_1", "f_2"],
    bounds=pd.DataFrame(l_bounds, u_bounds,
    columns=["h", "b", "l", "t"],
    index=["l_bounds", "u_bounds"]))
```

Any ideas what is the reason for this error with that index argument?

Comment: Please review:- https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple indexes in DataFrames, I would suggest using a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html)